# Summarize specific set of rows

Tags: r

I want to summarise the data of each item (multiple rows) in order to remove the items that haven't had any type of promotion. Please see the example data.

```
item_code vendor_code launch_month unit_price department_name  category_name
1  I-111164         V10     2007.M01        118            Face Face Treatment
2  I-111164         V10     2007.M01        118            Face Face Treatment
3  I-111164         V10     2007.M01        118            Face Face Treatment
4  I-111164         V10     2007.M01        118            Face Face Treatment
5  I-111164         V10     2007.M01        118            Face Face Treatment
6  I-111164         V10     2007.M01        118            Face Face Treatment
      subcategory_name sales_velocity sales_month sales_unit      promotion_type
1 Face Treatment Other              B    2008.M01   41.00000        no_promotion
2 Face Treatment Other              B    2008.M02   55.00000        no_promotion
3 Face Treatment Other              B    2008.M03   64.80000 Catalogue Promotion
4 Face Treatment Other              B    2008.M04   46.00000        no_promotion
5 Face Treatment Other              B    2008.M05   67.00000        no_promotion
6 Face Treatment Other              B    2008.M06   58.40000 Catalogue Promotion
>
```

What would be the best practice way to do this in **R**?

Comment: You could also do `dat[!grepl("no_promotion", dat$promotion_type),]`

Answer (score 1):

The following command returns a data frame without the rows that haven't had any type of promotion:

```
dat[dat$promotion_type != "no_promotion", ]
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
item_code <- rep(c("I-111164"), each = 1, times = 6)
vendor_code <- rep(c("V10"), each = 1, times = 6)
launch_month <- rep(c("2007.M01"), each = 1, times = 6)
unite_price <- rep(c("118"), each = 1, times = 6)
department_name <- rep(c("Face"), each = 1, times = 6)
category_name <- rep(c("Face Treatment"), each = 1, times = 6)
subcategory_name <- rep(c("Face Treatment other"), each = 1, times = 6)
sales_velocity <- rep(c("B"), each = 1, times = 6)
sales_month <- rep(c("2008.M01"), each = 1, times = 6)
sales_unit <- rep(c(41,55,64,46,67,58), each = 1, times = 1)
promotion_type <- c("no_promotion", "no_promotion", "catalogue promotion",
                "no_promotion", "no_promotion", "catalogue promotion")

# Create the data frame             
foo <- data.frame(item_code, vendor_code, launch_month, unite_price, department_name,
category_name, subcategory_name, sales_velocity, sales_month,sales_unit, promotion_type,    stringsAsFactors = F)

# Remove all rows with 'no_promotion'
foo2 <- filter(foo, promotion_type != "no_promotion")

# Get mean of sales unit for each item code
america <- foo2 %>%
       group_by(item_code) %>%
       summarize(sales = mean(sales_unit))

america
```

Answer (score 0):

First you want to get the item codes for all items that ever got a promotion.  Assuming your data frame is called `df`, use

```
got.promoted <- df$item_code[df$promotion_type != "no_promotion"]
```

This will be a vector with the right codes.  It may contain duplicates, which you can get rid of with

```
got.promoted <- unique(got.promoted)
```

Then use this vector to select, from the original data frame, the items that got promotions:

```
new.df <- df[df$item_code %in% got.promoted, ]
```

I won't claim that this is the "best practice" way, but it should work and is easy to understand.